# Adding custom field to the contact card without accounts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter, accountmanager, android-account

I'd like to add custom (related to my app) fields to the contact card, for instance, `"Message XXXX"` or `"Call XXXX"` on the XXXX contact card irrespective of whether XXXX has an account in my app. As in, my application should append these fields in all contact cards which the user has.

I don't have any information to sync with the contacts in my user's phone, but I want to be able to add those fields in the built-in contact (system app), which begs the question, is there a possible way to do this without having to create `account authenticators` and `sync adapters`?